# JS < (less than) Operator Failing

Tags: javascript, ajax, integer, setinterval

I have a script that AJAXes a request every 10 seconds (but technically 11), for the user. I have a simple countdown made from 10 to 0 and then again and again.

This `countit` function is called after each AJAX request to restart

Here is my code:

```
function countit() {
  var count = 10;
  loading = setInterval(function() {
    $(box).val("Will automatically check in " + count + "second(s), please DO NOT refresh the page yourself.");
    count--;
    if (count <= 0) {
      clearInterval(loading);
    }

  }, 1000);
}
```

The code works fine except, if you leave the page and come back, the countdown proceeds into negative and does not stop. Here is the image:

[image]

I cant be sure if this is a problem with the code or JS but the counter doesnt go below 0 when the user stays on the page.

Comment: How many times do you call `countit`? Because if you call it multiple times, only the last one will stop because of `loading` being a global variable! Or change the value of `loading` somewhere else will cause the problem too!

Comment: For safety change this: `loading = setIn...` to this: `var loading = setIn...`!

Comment: This does not happen on my console. It stops at 1s message

Comment: I have tried several times and I cannot get the problem you are talking about - whether I stay on the page or leave for a moment - it always stops at "1".

Comment: Yes, like Ibrahim said, loading is a global variable, and some other parts of your page may be interfering with the script you posted. Because by running the script as it is, it works fine! No matter what. So just follow Ibrahim's suggestion and change     loading = to     var loading =

Comment: @ibrahim changing to var didnt work.. still goes negative for some reason.. :|

Comment: Amresh & Curveball, I call the function after each AJAX request :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code except for `loading` be global and potentially changed somewhere else or by another of `countit` itself!

Comment: @user7071381 well, like everybody said, we all tried your function and it works as it should on our end. Something else is interfering with it, or maybe the function is being called more than once on the page for some reason. Open your browser console and check your AJAX requests. Maybe more than one is fired?

Comment: Just relised I needed to clear my cache for the JS to update, adding the var infront fixed it! Thanks Ibrahim, Chris and everyone else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ibrahim & Chris have said:

Add a var infront of the Interval as without it, the variable is global.

```
function countit() {
    var count = 10;
    var loading = setInterval(function() {
        $(box).val("Will automatically check in " + count + "second(s), please DO NOT refresh the page yourself.");
        count--;
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(loading);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```